# How to use async/await to get data from sqlite db.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I would like to get my data out from the sqlite db.each function using the promise object and the async/await I tried to do it but I don't really understand how to do it and I would like some explanations

my code below :

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.sqlite', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the database');
});

 function request (req) {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.each(req, function (err, row) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                data.push(row);
        }, function (err, n) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else
                resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

data = await request("select * from user "); //I'm getting errors here 



db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Close the database connection');
});
```

Comment: `new Promise(`    ->  `return new Promise(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` can only be used inside an `async` function. Create an async function, inside this function, await the `promise` returned by `request` function

```
async function makeRequest() {
    data = await request("select * from user ");
}
```

and you need to return the promise from `request` function so that it can be awaited

```
function request (req) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // code
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works . By the way could you say me how to extract the data out from the functions to put them in a global variable .

Comment: you could define `data` outside of the `makeRequest` function

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting undefined at console.log(data) even after define it globally

Comment: you will get undefined because data variable is initialized after an asynchronous request. Log `data` inside `makeRequest` function after the `await` statement

Comment: But the my goal is to log it how the async function that is what I want since the beginning .I fought that the using of async/await will permit me to do this simply but it is the same as when I used promise .Do you have a method to have it outside async function

Comment: code outside the `makeRequest` function executes before the async request is complete, so you won't be ablee to access data returned by the async request before it has finished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214449/discussion-between-esdras-zongo-and-yousaf).